# Pandas removes first character from value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset where I want to print the specific telephone number belonging to a specific userID.
The data set in question is:

```
#Leads.csv
USR_ID,Name,LastName,Gender,E-mail,Telephone
5iBR72rd28sdKlxSOQMffg,Iubhefsugus,fueshfs,Female,JO@jaja.co,0613829902
```

To do this I run these lines

```
df = pd.read_csv('Leads.csv')
readrow = df[(df['USR_ID'] == '5iBR72rd28sdKlxSOQMffg')]
print(readrow['Telephone'].item())`
```

and what I get is:
613829902

Does anyone know why this keeps happening, cause quite frankly I'm stumped.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the issue? Better use `df.loc[df['USR_ID'].eq('5iBR72rd28sdKlxSOQMffg'), 'Telephone'].squeeze()`. Also read your csv as string type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pandas attempts to convert the values to numeric if it can, and leading zeros are stripped out as they are noneffective. You can explicitly say you want "Telephone" column as strings:

```py
>>> pd.read_csv("file.csv", dtype={"Telephone": "str"})

                   USR_ID         Name LastName  Gender      E-mail   Telephone
0  5iBR72rd28sdKlxSOQMffg  Iubhefsugus  fueshfs  Female  JO@jaja.co  0613829902
```

and we see that leading 0 is there.

Comment: @WintrowVestrit Welcome to stackoverflow! You should accept the answer with green if works for you!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to read all columns as string then:

```
pd.read_csv('Leads.csv', dtype=str)
```

leading zeros will not be stripped.